# Python, Very simple scraping, how to sort?

Tags: python, request

My code:

```
import requests
resp = requests.get(url)

lines = resp.text.split('\n')
first_line = lines[0].split(',')
print(first_line[1])
```

Mu current code does not work, as the clan parameter is not in the same location each time. Maybe there is a regex I can use for this? Thank you all

My website output:

```
jQuery000000000000000_0000000000([{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":false,"name":"x","clan":"x","title":""}]);
```

I am looking to always get the `clan name`. It can be at a random location, it's not in a set order. Clan can have space in it. In this case I am trying to get x stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

import re, json

```
web_data = """jQuery000000000000000_0000000000([{"isSuffix":true,"recruiting":false,"name":"x","clan":"x","title":""}]);"""

result = re.search('\((.*)\)', web_data)
data = result.group(1)
dict_data = json.loads(data)
print(dict_data)

print(dict_data[0]["clan"])
```

Output:

```
>> [{'isSuffix': True, 'recruiting': False, 'name': 'x', 'clan': 'x', 'title': ''}]
>> x
```

EDIT 1:

```
 print(dict_data[0].get("clan"))
```

Comment: Sometimes the parameter clan is not on the page. Any idea how to add a fail safe for that?

Comment: @mskeo : You can use `.get`. Modified in EDIT 1 section